# Error creating new liferay module project in eclipse 2022-3

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay-7

i have a problem that i hope should be quite simple to solve but i just don't know how to do so myself.

I am working with eclipse 2022-3 and trying to develop with liferay 7.3.5 together with java 1.8. Recently I got a new laptop and have tried to move my old eclipse installation, together with my old workspace to my new laptop. However this has gone wrong somehow, my workspace is working correctly and I can work on my old module projects just fine. But **when trying to create a new Liferay module project, I get an error**:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.23.0.I20220308-0310
java.version=21.0.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jface
Error
Thu Jan 04 11:53:07 CET 2024
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Map java.security.SecureClassLoader.pdcache accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.security" to unnamed module @73909fd0
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:315)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:183)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1$1.run(CachedClass.java:52)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1.initValue(CachedClass.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1.initValue(CachedClass.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getFields(CachedClass.java:261)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addFields(MetaClassImpl.java:2374)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.inheritFields(MetaClassImpl.java:2369)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setupProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2256)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3299)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:872)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstStringCompiler.compile(AstStringCompiler.groovy:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilder.buildFromString(AstBuilder.groovy:100)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilder.buildFromString(AstBuilder.groovy)
    at com.liferay.ide.gradle.core.model.GradleBuildScript.<init>(GradleBuildScript.java:64)
    at com.liferay.ide.gradle.core.model.GradleBuildScript.<init>(GradleBuildScript.java:53)
    at com.liferay.ide.gradle.core.model.GradleBuildScript.<init>(GradleBuildScript.java:49)
    at com.liferay.ide.gradle.core.LiferayGradleWorkspaceProject.isFlexibleLiferayWorkspace(LiferayGradleWorkspaceProject.java:384)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.ui.RequireLiferayWorkspaceProject.promptIfLiferayWorkspaceNotExists(RequireLiferayWorkspaceProject.java:76)
    at com.liferay.ide.project.ui.modules.NewLiferayModuleProjectWizard.init(NewLiferayModuleProjectWizard.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage.lambda$0(NewWizardNewPage.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1542)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1063)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewProjectAction.run(NewProjectAction.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1063)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

I will only get this error on the logs if I go through new -> project -> liferay -> liferay module project. Otherwise it will simply not work and refuse to say anything.

I have tried to update my liferay plugin on eclipse and also removed it and reinstalled it. I tried adding some settings to my gradle properties file but that didn't solve it. Other than that i searched on google for a solution but couldn't really find anything

as requested this is my eclipse.ini file(i replaced my username with the word user):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.400.v20211117-0650
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.23.0.20220310-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Users/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.1.v20231028-0937/jre/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
-Djava.security.manager=allow
-Dswt.enable.autoScale=true
-Dswt.autoScale=150
-Dswt.autoScale.method=nearest
```

this is my run configuration:
[image: As you can see i have some warning next to my java home, but clicking or hovering over it doesn't show anything]

I'm hoping someone had this problem before and can help me solve it?

Comment: That message can only come from Java 9 or later so you are not using Java 8 to run your code. Check that you have your project configured correctly for Java 8. Note that chatgpt is not a programming tool and can't be relied on for  technical problems like this.

Comment: @greg-449 oh that's strange. I only have one jdk installed and that is 1.8.0_281, this is also listed in my installed jre's list in eclipse preferences and active there. Could it be that somehow my eclipse is using something else?

oh and i wasn't relying on chatgpt, i just wanted to have it said that i did try some things to solve it myself besides just googling. But i can remove that part from the question

Comment: Most Eclipse installs come with a built in Java 17 you may be using that. Look at the build path in the project properties.

Comment: Also check the Run Configuration.

Comment: @greg-449 I have the same jdk selected there as i have under preferences, and i checked the path and it is correct. I'm also using a specific gradle version, the same as i had on my previous laptop.

there is one thing though, there is an orange exclamation mark next to the browse button where you select the java home. Hovering on it doesn't do anything neither does clicking it so i don't know what it means?

Comment: About which browse button do you talk (in which dialog)? Is there something in the _Problems_ view? Eclipse 2022-03 is six releases behind. Can your issue be reproduced with the current Eclipse and with the current Liferay plugin? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with `eclipse.buildId=` and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question. If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.

Comment: @howlger The browse button i mentioned is under Run -> Run configurations and then select Project Settings with the gradle icon. Under advanced Options there is a setting for Java home, that has a warning sign next to it. There is nothing in the Problems view except for a view warnings about some of my code.

I will start working on the other issues you mentioned and then edit my question. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: The issues shown in the _Error Log_ view are related to the Java which with you run Eclipse. In contrast, warnings and errors shown in your project (settings) are related to the Java that you use in your project. Please show a screenshot of your run configuration. Is there a message shown at the top or bottom of the run configuration or when you hover the error/warning icon? What have you configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_?

Comment: @howlger I added the rest of my error as requested and also have added a screenshot of my run configuration. There is a warning showed in that screen but it doesn't show anything when hovering or clicking on it.
In my preferences I have the jdk that i want to use, which is 1.8. It is also selected and i changed the compiler to work with that version of java. I already had these settings configured on my old laptop

Comment: According to the error log, you run a quite old Eclipse with Java 21 which is the latest Java version. I guess the Liferay plugin that causing the issue that is logged is even older. In Java 16 and 17 accessing private fields via reflection became more restrictive which might causing this `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException`. Does running your outdated Eclipse with Java 11 work (before Eclipse 2022-09 Java 11 or higher was required and since Eclipse 2022-09 Java 17 or higher is required; it is recommended to use the Java that is shipped with Eclipse to run Eclipse)?

Comment: @howlger i don't understand how that is possible... I have java jdk1.8.0_281 downloaded and selected in both the run configuration screen and in my preferences. In my gradle properties it is also defined, by the org.gradle.java.home variable. I apologise for my lack of knowledge on this subject but am I missing something?

Comment: The Java you use in your project (to compile and to run) and to run Gradle can differ from the Java that is used to run Eclipse. The Java to run Eclipse can be part of Eclipse: if in _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details_ there is [_JustJ_](https://eclipse.dev/justj/), then a Java JDK is part of Eclipse. Please try to install or unzip a Java 11 JRE or JDK (e.g. from [adoptium.net](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11&os=windows&arch=x64)) and [setting it in the `eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example). Please show your `eclipse.ini`

Comment: Please note, in `eclipse.ini`, `-vm` and the path must be two separate lines, directly above the line `-vmargs` (the `eclipse.ini` will also tell which Java installation currently is used).

Comment: @howlger I checked my installation details in eclipse and JustJ is in there. Also i will edit my question to include my eclipse ini file. But like i said, i want to use java 8, and according to liferay's website the version of liferay which i want to use is compatible with java 8 and with eclipse.

Comment: Yes, you already said that, but the Java you want to use in your project(s) is a different thing than the Java used to run Eclipse with the Liferay plugin. The question you haven't answered yet is whether it works if you run your outdated Eclipse with Java 11.

Comment: @howlger aahh okay. I'll try that and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: @howlger I downloaded java 11 from the website you mentioned and i edited my eclipse.ini file with this:
-vm
C:/Users/user/Java/jdk-11.0.21+9/bin

but this doesn't seem to work. When trying to open eclipse it shows me the start up logo for a second and then disappears without actually starting the application. The java files are in that location, i copied it directly.

Comment: Please do the following: On the command line, go to the Eclipse installation directory and run it from the command line via `eclipse -vm C:/Users/user/Java/jdk-11.0.21+9/bin` and tell if something is printed.

Comment: @howlger when i type that command in the eclipse installation directory (the same location as the eclipse.ini file?) i only get this:
'eclipse' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

i assume i'm meant to run it elsewhere?

Comment: You said you edited your eclipse.ini file with `-vm C:/Users/user/Java/jdk-11.0.21+9/bin`, but your question still shows the line `C:/Users/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.1.v20231028-0937/jre/bin` instead of `C:/Users/user/Java/jdk-11.0.21+9/bin`. `-vm` and the path have to be separate lines directly before the line `-vmargs`. If you haven't done exactly that, it won't work. On the command line you can run `"<path to eclipse.exe>\eclipse.exe" -vm C:\Users\user\Java\jdk-11.0.21+9\bin`.